# Moving a div dynamically with keystrokes vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, 2d-games

I am building a simple Pirates clone in the browser, and using regular javascript with no libraries in an attempt to learn the basics. I am trying to move a relative positioned div that is my game sprite, within an absolute positioned div that is the game board. I have all of the code up to the point of actually moving the div, I just cant find the command to change the relative positioning of a div.

Here is what I have:

```
function move(e){
    var x=e.keyCode;
    var keychar=String.fromCharCode(x);
    if (x === "a") {
       // What goes here?
    }
};
```

Comment: That should probably be `if (keychar === "a")`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to move it by modifying `el.style.left` and `el.style.top` where `el` is a reference to your positioned `DIV`.

Answer (score 1):

Change(increase or decrease) the `divElement.style.left` value in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

First, your inner div should have `position: absolute`, not `relative`. The outer one could have either. Then it's just a matter of setting `style.top` and `style.left` on every keystroke:

```
function move(e){
    var x=e.keyCode;
    var keychar=String.fromCharCode(x).toLowerCase();
    var div = document.getElementById('mydiv');
    if (x === "a") {
        var currentLeft = parseInt(div.style.left, 10);
        // to move left:
        div.style.left = (currentLeft-5) + 'px';
    }
};
```

That should work, but your sprite may not move as smoothly as you expect. In that case, you'll probably need an animation loop, and a keystroke buffer.

Comment: You're right, I totally got the absolute/relative thing backwards and I just realized it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `style.left` and `style.top`

```
var d = document.getElementById("idselector");
d.style.left = "30px";
d.style.top = "40px";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.getElementById("divId");

if(x == "a"){        
    div.position.left = (parseInt(div.style.left) - 10) + "px";
}
else if(x == "d"){
    div.position.left = (parseInt(div.style.left) + 10) + "px";
}

// similar code for other keys with div.style.top
```